# Error Exception: No such proxy method: YandexMobileAds.Platforms.Android.cl.onAdLoaded(UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads, yandex

I'm using unity 22.3.16f1
I have an error when working with the Yandex Mobile Ads SDK https://ads.yandex.com/helpcenter/ru/dev/platforms

After I make a build for android, the test advertisement does not run.
In android studio, I get the error Exception in the logs: No such proxy method: Yandex Mobile Maps.Platforms.Android.cl.onAdLoaded(UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject)

I tried to import the Yandex Mobile Ads SDK again

I tried to run it on devices with a newer or older version of android

I tried to search for the error in Google

There are no results.

Yandex Mobile Ads SDK was installed according to the instructions and all custom settings were specified.
Maybe someone has come across and knows what else can be checked?

Answer (score 0):

I spent 6 hours on this, but finally found what the problem was.

The problem was with the plugin

Obfuscator Free

https://guardingpearsoftware.com/?docs=obfuscator)

I added a setting to the plugin to exclude YandexMobileAds
after that everything worked.

I hope my answer helps someone.